# error in SQL query, can't figure out the syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

I am new to mysql db programming, i am not able to figure out what is the error in the mysql insert statement i am executing. MySql Query browser is giving error: error in your SQL syntax.

Structure of my database table:

[image: Table Structure]

Command:

```
insert into mail_client.inbox ( to , from , subject , date , message ,   uuid ) 
values ( "fdfgmail.com" , "fromgmail.com" , "subj" , "2016-06-06" , "hello" , 
"0757c2666e934e2eb303df68bb3c9722" );
```

Comment: `to` and `from` are reserved words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add backticks to the reserved names fields:

```
`insert into mail_client.inbox ( `to` , `from` , subject , `date` , message ,   uuid ) values ( "fdfgmail.com" , "fromgmail.com" , "subj" , "2016-06-06" , "hello" , "0757c2666e934e2eb303df68bb3c9722" );`
```

Comment: `date` isn't a reserved word. It's a keyword, but not reserved.